# Are Duality and the Inner-Product inextricably linked?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra, the dual $A^*:W^*\to V^*$ of a map $A:V\to W$ is defined by
$$\langle Av,w\rangle=\langle v,A^*w\rangle$$
Does this mean that something like $A^*$ has no meaning without the context of an inner-product space?

Comment: In that context, $\langle\,\cdot\,,\,\cdot\,\rangle$ does not denote an inner product, but the natural pairing $W\times W^\ast \to \mathbb{K}$ on the left, and $V\times V^\ast \to \mathbb{K}$ on the right. The dual (or transpose, or adjoint) of a continuous linear map is related to but different from the Hilbert-space adjoint in the case of (pre-)Hilbert spaces. It exists in far more general settings.

Comment: @DanielFischer I suspect that this comment is incomprehensible to the OP. It is to me. Please try to avoid answering questions in the comments section. Why not elaborate on your comment by posting a nice, well-explain answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $A : V \to W$ be a linear map between vector spaces.

Let $\mathrm{f} : W \to \mathbb{R}$ be a linear function on $W$. We can define the pull-back of $\mathrm{f}$ to $V$ which is a linear function on $V$. The pull-back of $\mathrm{f}$, denoted by $A^*\mathrm{f}$, is defined as follows:

$$(A^*\mathrm{f})(v) := \mathrm{f}\!\left(A(v)\right)$$

This does not need any idea of an inner product. Once you define an inner product then you can express the definition of the pull-back in terms of this inner product, but it is not necessary.

Answer (score 2):

If $A:V\to W$ is linear, there is a map from $W^*$ to $V^*$ that sends $f$ in $W^*$ to the composition $f\circ A$ in $V^*$. (So if $v\in V$, then $f\circ A$ maps $v$ to $f(Av)$.)

This map from $W^*$ to $V^*$ is linear, and is denoted by $A^*$. It is defined without reference to any inner product or pairing.